# Update/change text on widget

Tags: unreal-engine5

I have a widget that has basic info on a card. The blueprint of the card holds the img and background. The BP deck creator generates the card with the card info on it, but when I change the text, nothing happens.

[the text is spawned and editable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVknR.png)